# Is there a GPIO visual plotter for Raspberry like Arduino's Serial Plotter

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, display

Arduino has a "Serial plotter" that displays gpio status/value in a simple graphical view similar to an oscilloscope.
Is there a similar for (easy to use, no frills) for Raspberry?

Answer (score 4):

[piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) is a digital waveform viewer for the Raspberry Pi.

It shows the state of each GPIO on the expansion header in "real-time".